# Using iterator in loop without causing any exceptions

Tags: java, iterator

I used iterator class to solve a question.
I thought that iterator() method of HashSet returns the collection of its iterator.
But whenever I ran this code(especially the 5th line) it occurs ConcurrentModificationException, even though I've checked the iterator has next elements.

Sorry for my bad English, but I really want to find out what's wrong with my code and fix the problems.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    iterator = set.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int num = iterator.next();
        if (!set.contains(num + input)) set.add(num + input);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't modify the `Collection` after creating the `Iterator` being used, except via `Iterator#remove()`, without (a high likelihood of) getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: One hint on coding style: put the `set.add(num + input);` on its own line. It's not only more readable, but also better for debugging, as then Java will tell you that it was exactly that statement causing the exception.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for your help. Now I see what's the problem of my code. I should try other way to solve this problem.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I accept your advice. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the Adds in a local Set/List.

after iterating overall, just add them all

```
Set toAdd = new HashSet();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    iterator = set.iterator();
    toAdd.clear();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int num = iterator.next();
        if (!set.contains(num + input)) toAdd.add(num + input);
    }
    set.addAll(toAdd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I tried this code and it didn't occur the exception. But I'm worried that the method `addAll()` could take too long time when the `N` is huge.

Comment: I guess if N is getting that big, your function would be also slow in general, as you continuous call an insert function. You may have look in to an algo with sorted lists and a for loop

Comment: Or `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) { int input = scan.nextInt(); for(int num: new ArrayList<>(set)) set.add(num + input); }`, skipping all the redundant work.